# Azure Cognitive Index c# code to push data into index

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search

Not through lack of investigation has anyone got any c# code to push a json document into a Cognitive Search Index?
I can populate the index using the GUI in Azure Portal so I know all the plumbing is working but what I'm not sure about is how do I push one or more new records into the index.
All the MS documentation says I can do it but I find it very difficult to find an example of how to do it from c#.

I'm using the using the following namespaces:

> Azure.Search.Documents.Models;
> Azure.Search.Documents;

If someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the SDK you're using.

Answer (score 0):

To create an index and submit objects for indexing using the .Net SDK, you can follow the examples here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-dotnet-sdk

The examples use a model to represent a Hotel object. If you have your data represented in JSON, you can deserialize your data to objects that you submit to the index. Also known as unmarshaling. See

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0

Tip: Start by completing the hotel example and get that working. Once that is working, you can try to serialize a hotel object to a JSON file. Then deserialize that JSON file back to an object and submit it to the index. Once you have that working, you should be able to create your own, custom index and submit objects based on your JSON file.